# ES6/Next: object destructuring with rest - grouping

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, ecmascript-next

I have:

```
const props = {
  gallery: [],
  select: () => null,
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
}
```

I can destructure it with:

```
const {gallery, select, ...other} = props
```

I will have three variables now:

- **gallery** = `[]`
- **select** = `() => null`
- **other** = `{one: 1,two: 2}`

Is it possible to destucture to a specify grouping?

Something like this(this is not going to work but I hope it is clear to see what I am trying to do):

```
const {{gallery, select}: specific, ...other} = props
```

So I will have 2 variables:

- **specific** = `{gallery: [], select: () => null}`
- **other** = `{one: 1,two: 2}`

I could solve it at the higher level and build the props in this way:

```
const props = {
  specific: {
    gallery: [],
    select: () => null,
  },
  other: {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
  }
}
```

But I am just wondering if this is possible with destructuring.

Comment: Probably could be done with [spread properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread#spread-properties) but that's not available in ES6 yet

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It will never be available in ES6. ES6 specification was already finalized.

Comment: @Gothdo Ambiguous wording, I meant it's not available in ES version 6 yet, but may be in later ones.

Comment: _"I can destructur it with:"_ Not with ES6. Or any other specified version of ES. `...other` is not (yet) a valid expression in any existing ES standard.

Comment: I updated the question to mention ES7 instead of ES6, because indeed, object rest syntax is not available in ES6 and proposed for ES7.

Comment: @trincot ES7 is the name for ES2016 (at least unofficially). The dialect you're referring to is ES.next. It isn't obvious that the OP expects it to be ES.next and not ES6.

Comment: You're right, @estus, the object rest property didn't make it into ES7. ES.Next -- however dynamic the name -- it is then. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

What about this? `others` contains also the `specific` data and I must access first to the `props` (maybe this could be improved), but I think that it basically groups while destructuring. It works because you can assign a default value when the attribute does not exist:

```js
const props = {
  gallery: [],
  select: () => null,
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
}

const {gallery : gal, select : sel} = props;
const {specific: specific={gallery: gal, select: sel}, ...others} = props;

console.log(specific);
console.log(others);
```

**EDIT**

You can also change

```
const {gallery : gal, select : sel} = props;
const {specific: specific={gallery: gal, select: sel}, ...others} = props;
```

with:

```
const {specific: specific={gallery: props.gallery, select: props.select}, ...others} = props;
```

if you want it in one line.

Also, [maioman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40400103/6499571) solves the problem I mentioned with `others` containing the `specific` data and doesn't directly access props.

Answer (score 9):

Stretching syntax (and readability) to the limit you could do this:

(explanation to the code is in the comments)

```js
const props = {
  gallery: [],
  select: () => null,
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
}

/** destructuring assignment **/
const {
  gallery, //extract the gallery prop
  select, //extract the select prop
  specific: specific={gallery, select},
  // create `specific` setting gallery and select props through default value assignment 
  ...others // assign to others the rest of non extracted props properties
} = props;

console.log(specific);
console.log(others);
```

In the end we get a `gallery` and a `select` object in the scope but we have succeeded to make them also properties of a new `specific` object.

Usage warning: object spread is still a proposal

Comment: I am pretty new to stackoverflow, so I'm not really sure and i might be wrong with my assumption, but it seems like you have used my answer and changed it... shouldn't you have commented in mine instead of posting a new answer if that's the case?

Comment: @CésarLandesa even if snippet shares same boilerplate, the solution is different, so IMHO it's ok...

Comment: But the solution is based on the same idea to resolve the main problem: using the default value to group when destructuring... then you improved that concept, for sure, but based on my code and main idea. I guess that it's a matter of perspective, but to me it looks like a modification to my idea, and not a different enough solution.

Comment: @CésarLandesa the way I see it is that destructuring assignment is useful when it's a single expression and this is the core of what I proposed vs. what you proposed